# Blackjack game with database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, mysql, playing-cards

This is the latest version of my Blackjack game and I did a quite big update to it. Now you can make an account that is saved in the MySQL database and you can bet money that are also saved in the database.

```
from random import shuffle
import os
import cymysql
from getpass import getpass
import sys


def shuffled_shoe():
    shoe = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'A', 'J', 'Q', 'K']*4
    shuffle(shoe)
    return shoe


def deal_card(shoe, person, number):
    for _ in range(number):
        person.append(shoe.pop())


def deal_hand(shoe, player, dealer):
    deal_card(shoe, player, 2)
    deal_card(shoe, dealer, 2)


def score(person):
    non_aces = [c for c in person if c != 'A']
    aces = [c for c in person if c == 'A']
    total = 0
    for card in non_aces:
        if card in 'JQK':
            total += 10
        else:
            total += int(card)
    for card in aces:
        if total <= 10:
            total += 11
        else:
            total += 1
    return total


def display_info(still_playing, player, dealer, money, money_bet, player_stands):
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print(f"Money: ${money}")
    print(f"Money bet: ${money_bet}")
    print("Your cards:   [{}] ({})".format("][".join(player), score(player)))
    if player_stands:
        print("Dealer cards: [{}] ({})".format("][".join(dealer), score(dealer)))
    else:
        print("Dealer cards: [{}][?]".format(dealer[0]))
    first_hand = len(dealer) == 2
    if score(player) == 21:
        print("Blackjack! You won")
        still_playing = False
        money += money_bet * 2
    elif first_hand and score(dealer) == 21:
        print("Dealer got a blackjack. You lost!")
        still_playing = False
    elif score(player) > 21:
        print("Busted! You lost!")
        still_playing = False
    if player_stands:
        if score(dealer) > 21:
            print("Dealer busted! You won")
            money += money_bet * 2
        elif score(player) > score(dealer):
            print("You beat the dealer! You won!")
            money += money_bet * 2
        elif score(player) < score(dealer):
            print("Dealer has beaten you. You lost!")
        else:
            print("Push. Nobody wins or losses.")
            money += money_bet
        still_playing = False
    return still_playing, money


def hit_or_stand():
    while True:
        print("What do you choose?")
        print("[1] Hit")
        print("[2] Stand")
        ans = input("> ")
        if ans in '12':
            return ans


def bet():
    print("How much money do you want to bet?")
    money = int(input("> "))
    return money


def player_play(shoe, player, dealer, money, money_bet, player_plays, player_stands):
    while not player_stands:
        if hit_or_stand() == '2':
            player_stands = True
            player_plays = False
        elif not player_stands:
            deal_card(shoe, player, 1)
            display_info(True, player, dealer, money, money_bet, player_stands)
            if score(player) >= 21:
                player_plays = False
                break
    return player_plays, player_stands


def dealer_play(shoe, dealer, DEALER_MINIMUM_SCORE):
    while score(dealer) <= DEALER_MINIMUM_SCORE:
        deal_card(shoe, dealer, 1)
    return False


def play_again(cur, money, email):
    while True:
        print("\nDo you want to play again?")
        print("[1] Yes")
        print("[2] No")
        ans = input("> ")
        if ans == '1':
            return True
        elif ans == '2':
            cur.execute("UPDATE `users` SET `money`=%s WHERE `email`=%s", (money, email))
            cur.close()
            return False


def get_user_info():
    while True:
        email = input("Email address (max. 255 chars.): ")
        password = getpass("Password (max. 255 chars.): ")
        if len(email) < 255 and len(password) < 255:
            return email, password


def register(cur, email, password):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`Email`, `Password`) VALUES (%s, %s)", (email, password))


def login(cur, email, password):
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email`=%s AND `Password`=%s LIMIT 1", (email, password))
    return bool(cur.fetchall())


def check_account(cur, email):
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email`=%s LIMIT 1", (email,))
    return bool(cur.fetchone())


def start():
    print("Do you want to start playing? (Y)es/(N)o")
    ans = input("> ").lower()
    if ans == 'y':
        return True
    elif ans == 'n':
        return False


def main():
    conn = cymysql.connect(
        host='127.0.0.1',
        user='root',
        passwd='',
        db='blackjack'
    )
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        email, password = get_user_info()
        checked = check_account(cur, email)
        if checked:
            loggedin = login(cur, email, password)
            if loggedin:
                print("You've succesfully logged-in!")
            else:
                print("You failed logging-in!")
                sys.exit()
        else:
            register(cur, email, password)
            print("You've succesfully registered and recieved $1000!")
        cur.execute("SELECT `money` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=%s", (email,))
        money = cur.fetchone()
        cash = money[0]
    keeps_playing = start()
    while keeps_playing:
        shoe = shuffled_shoe()
        player = []
        dealer = []
        still_playing = True
        player_plays = True
        player_stands = False
        money_bet = bet()
        cash -= money_bet
        deal_hand(shoe, player, dealer)
        still_playing, cash = display_info(still_playing, player, dealer, cash, money_bet, player_stands)
        while still_playing:
            while player_plays:
                player_plays, player_stands = player_play(shoe, player, dealer, cash, money_bet, player_plays, player_stands)
            still_playing = dealer_play(shoe, dealer, 17)
        still_playing, cash = display_info(still_playing, player, dealer, cash, money_bet, player_stands)
        keeps_playing = play_again(cur, cash, email)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple possible bugs:

- When a user registers, there's text saying that they get $1000 to start. I don't see where this money comes from in the code.
- In `display_info()`, if `player_stands` is `True`, I think it could be possible to display both "Busted! You lost!" and ""Dealer busted! You won"

I don't see the point of passing `still_playing` to `display_info`. If we don't pass it, set `still_playing` to `True` at the start of the function, the overall behavior doesn't change.

I think `display_info()` is doing an awful lot. It:

- shows the current state
- determines the winner
- changes the player's money, and
- Tells you who won/lost

I would try to separate these out.

`hit_or_stand()` returns a number, so the caller has to remember what it means. Consider using a constant or an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) instead.

The user's password gets stored in plaintext. Consider encrypting it.

It seems unconventional to have a function parameter be in all caps. Per PEP 8:

> Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include MAX_OVERFLOW and TOTAL."

So it would look more natural to do, e.g.

```
import sys

DEALER_MINIMUM_SCORE = 17

[...]

def dealer_play(shoe, dealer):
    while score(dealer) <= DEALER_MINIMUM_SCORE:
        deal_card(shoe, dealer, 1)
    return False
```

or maybe

```
def dealer_play(shoe, dealer, dealer_minimum_score):
    while score(dealer) <= dealer_minimum_score:
        deal_card(shoe, dealer, 1)
    return False

[...]

still_playing = dealer_play(shoe, dealer, DEALER_MINIMUM_SCORE)
```

Comment: First bug won't happen because in the database I chose 'money' to have a default value of 1000. Second bug won't happen either. If I set still_playing as True and I don't pass it to display_info, then if I get a Blackjack, I will have to play the entire game to see that. I will try to split display_info a bit.